# Why omnet++ 4.6 simulation stops during runtime?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am trying to simulate the program in omnet++ 4.6 and I'm trying to develop my MAC  code. When I try to simulate the program, it shows "simulating sfmac (0%)"  and after a long time it is still in the same situation, showing "simulating sfmac (0%)" at the bottom site of the gui.

I even reinstalled the omnet++ 4.6 program but it works for first time and again arise the same problem.

I am using windows 8 pro operating system , 8gb ram as well as using windows defender and the defender always updated.

the problem image are attached in the below section.

[omnet++ progress bar output](http://www.mediafire.com/view/ffyv4qpaz3gy1d3/100.jpg)

[omnet++ problem bar output](http://www.mediafire.com/view/xn5fa1s4tvdxwqm/problem.jpg)

[omnet++ console bar output](http://www.mediafire.com/view/7jvheptyv9x3aij/problem1.jpg)

Need help please.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the screenshots you have submitted. The simulation started successfully and most likely waiting you to start it on the Tkenv GUI. I hope you have figured out that the IDE actually starts a separate process with its own GUI where you should start the simulation on the toolbar.